# Is there an overall accepted name for no-material renders?

Tags: materials

Whitemat, whitecard (more for architecture), nomat, pure-render.
Is there any name for these that is standard ?

I can't imagine something that is so widely used to have no specific name.

Comment: Do you mean Clay Render?

Comment: reference image what you need

Comment: [Clay render](https://www.google.com/search?q=clay+render&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja-fKw2bnXAhVJhlQKHesaCsQQsAQIJw&biw=1920&bih=965)